# Logical disjunction in elementary toposes

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

I'm following Goldbaltt's *Topoi: The categorial analysis of logic*. I use this book's notation, but it is quite standard.

At some point, he defines *disjunction* as the morphism
$$\curlyvee:\Omega\times\Omega\longrightarrow\Omega$$
which is the character of the image of the morphism
$$w=[\langle\top_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_{\Omega}\rangle,\langle\mathbf{1}_\Omega,\top_\Omega\rangle]:\Omega+\Omega\longrightarrow\Omega\times\Omega$$
Using the epi-mono factorization
$$w=\text{im}(w)w^*:\Omega+\Omega\to w(\Omega+\Omega)\to\Omega\times\Omega$$
I have managed to prove that
$$\top\curlyvee\top = \curlyvee\langle\top,\top\rangle=\curlyvee\langle\top !_\Omega\top,\mathbf{1}_\Omega\top\rangle=\curlyvee\langle\top !_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_\Omega\rangle\top=\curlyvee wi_1\top=$$
$$=\curlyvee\text{im}(w)w^*i_1\top=\top!_{w(\Omega+\Omega)}w^*i_1\top=\top!_{\Omega+\Omega}i_1\top=\top !_\Omega\top=\top$$
And similary, using $\curlyvee\text{im}(w)w^*i_1\bot$ and $\curlyvee\text{im}(w)w^*i_2\bot$ it can be proven that
$$\top\curlyvee\bot=\bot\curlyvee\top = \top$$

I'm having lots of trouble proving that $\bot\curlyvee\bot = \bot$.
Goldblatt himself leaves this unproven until much later in the book, after he has developed other tools to work with truth values. However I would like a diagram-chasing proof that doesn't require introducing new definitions and lemmas.

I've already tried many things (and failed): trying to replicate a proof from the topos of sets, trying to use the universal property of the image of $w$ together with the $\Omega$-axiom...

Whatever I try, I can't complete the diagram with the key morphism.

Is it possible to find the proof I'm looking for?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have available the fact that unions of subobjects are stable under pullbacks?  If so, then the morphism corresponds to the natural transformation $\operatorname{Sub} \times \operatorname{Sub} \to \operatorname{Sub}$ which takes such unions; and the fact that $\bot \lor \bot = \bot$ then corresponds to the fact that the union of two initial subobjects of 1 is again the initial subobject of 1.  (And more generally, you could get that $\bot \lor {-} : \Omega \to \Omega$ is the identity.)

Comment: And I guess unions of subobjects being stable under pullbacks would follow from images and coproducts being stable under pullbacks.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I would rather not use it. I think it rests on the fundamental theorem (of topos theory) that the slice category (over any object) is also an elementary topos, which I want to avoid

Comment: OK...  On some level, I think what you're running into is that $p \le (p \lor q)$ and $q \le (p \lor q)$ are sufficient to decide the cases you've solved; but to prove $(\bot \lor \bot) = \bot$, you need the minimality condition that if $p \le r$ and $q \le r$ then $(p \lor q) \le r$.  Not sure off the top of my head how to prove such a thing directly.

Comment: An alternate definition of $\lor$ I can think of: first, define a morphism $(\Omega\times\Omega)\times\Omega\to\Omega$ by $(\pi_1\circ\pi_1 \rightarrow \pi_2) \land (\pi_2\circ\pi_1 \rightarrow \pi_2)$, and take the corresponding morphism $\Omega\times\Omega\to P\Omega$.  On the other hand, consider the morphism of composition $! : \Omega\to 1$, $true : 1 \to \Omega$, $\{\}_\Omega:\Omega\to P\Omega$.  Finally, apply $=_{P\Omega}$ to the two to get ${\lor} : \Omega\times\Omega\to\Omega$...

Comment: It should be possible to show the two definitions agree, and it should be easier to calculate $\bot\lor\bot$.  But I'm guessing this would be firmly in the "new definitions and lemmas" camp, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a direct series of computations as you were asking for.  However, I did find an argument that hopefully is reasonably elementary.

First, considering the monomorphism $(\bot, \bot) : 1 \to \Omega \times \Omega$, observe that since $(\bot_\Omega, 1_\Omega) : \Omega \to \Omega \times \Omega$ is the pullback of $\bot : 1 \to \Omega$ along $\pi_1 : \Omega\times\Omega \to \Omega$, we have
$$\chi_{(\bot,\bot)} \circ (\top_\Omega, 1_\Omega) \le \chi_{(\bot_\Omega, 1_\Omega)} \circ (\top_\Omega, 1_\Omega) = \chi_\bot \circ \pi_1 \circ (\top_\Omega, 1_\Omega) = \chi_\bot \circ \top \circ {!}_\Omega = \bot !_\Omega.$$
Now, since $\bot !_\Omega$ is the minimum element of $\operatorname{Hom}(\Omega, \Omega)$, we conclude that $\chi_{(\bot,\bot)} \circ (\top_\Omega, 1_\Omega) = \bot !_\Omega$.  A similar argument, using $\pi_2$ in place of $\pi_1$, shows that $\chi_{(\bot,\bot)} \circ (1_\Omega, \top_\Omega) = \bot !_\Omega$ also.  Therefore, $\chi_{(\bot,\bot)} \circ w = \bot !_{\Omega+\Omega}$.

Now, since $\bar w$ is an epimorphism, we get that $\chi_{(\bot,\bot)} \circ \operatorname{im} (w) = \bot !_{w(\Omega\times\Omega)}$.  As a result, we have a pullback diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0 @>>> w(\Omega\times\Omega) \\
@VVV @VV \operatorname{im}(w) V \\
1 @> (\bot,\bot) >> \Omega\times\Omega.
\end{CD}$$
Now flipping this diagram and reading it the other way, we can conclude that $\curlyvee \circ (\bot,\bot) = \chi_{\operatorname{im}(w)} \circ (\bot,\bot) = \bot$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I worked out the complete proof from your answer

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I post here what I've worked out.

Thanks to the great answer by Daniel Schelper I managed to get the type of proof I wanted by completing some (easily provable) details:

1. In an elementary topos (more generally a cartesian-closed category) it is true that every morphism $f:x\to \mathbf{0}$ is iso, so that $x\cong\mathbf{0}$
2. For all objects $x$, it is true that
   $$\chi_{\mathbf{0}_x}=\bot !_x$$
3. If $\top !_x=\bot !_x$, then $x\cong \mathbf{0}$
4. $[\mathbf{0}_x]$ is the minimum of $\text{Sub}_\mathbf{C}(x)$ for any object $x$

and at least 6 rather simple observations (which I made in spanish for my own notes on the subject, but shouldn't be difficult to translate):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As a brief comment: in what I wrote, I was thinking at one point that for $p, q : 1 \to \Omega$, we have $\chi_p \circ q$ and $\chi_q \circ p$ are both the characteristic function of the pullback of $p$ and $q$.  And of course, the two maps to $1$ must be equal, so the subobjects are the same in either direction.  Therefore, $\chi_p \circ q = \chi_q \circ p$.  So in particular, $\chi_\bot \circ \top = \chi_\top \circ \bot$.  On the other hand, $\chi_\top = 1_\Omega$ pretty much by definition of $\top$; so $\chi_bot \circ \top = \bot$.