# Asociativity of disjunction in elementary toposes

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory, associativity

This is a continuation from a previous question of mine about [Logical disjunction in elementary toposes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789908/logical-disjunction-in-elementary-toposes)

I managed to prove conmutativity of both $\curlywedge$ and $\curlyvee$ (conjunction and disjunction as defined in Goldblatt's book *Topoi*) as well as asociativity of $\curlywedge$ by proving the relatively stronger result that
$$\curlywedge\langle\pi_{1},\curlywedge\langle\pi_{2},\pi_{3}\rangle\rangle=\curlywedge\langle\pi_{\sigma(1)},\curlywedge\langle\pi_{\sigma(2)},\pi_{\sigma(3)}\rangle\rangle$$
for any permutation $\sigma\in\text{Sym}(3)$.

I did this by proving that $\curlywedge\langle\pi_{\sigma(1)},\curlywedge\langle\pi_{\sigma(2)},\pi_{\sigma(3)}\rangle\rangle$ is the character morphism of $\langle\top,\top,\top\rangle$ independently of $\sigma$, which is relatively easy.

Conmutativity for $\curlywedge$ can be proven using the universal property of the epi-mono factorization of
$$w=[\langle\top_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_\Omega\rangle,\langle\mathbf{1}_\Omega,\top_\Omega\rangle]$$
and the fact that
$$\langle\pi_{2},\pi_{1}\rangle w[i_{2},i_{1}]=w$$

However, disjunction is not easily generalizable as conjunction. I've tried similar ideas by finding the adequate $w$ for "three inputs", like
$$w_3=[\langle\top_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_\Omega\rangle,\langle\mathbf{1}_\Omega,\top_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_\Omega\rangle,\langle\mathbf{1}_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_\Omega,\top_\Omega\rangle]$$
or
$$w_3=[\langle\top_\Omega,\top_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_\Omega\rangle,\langle\top_\Omega,\mathbf{1}_\Omega,\top_\Omega\rangle,\langle\mathbf{1}_\Omega,\top_\Omega,\top_\Omega\rangle]$$

Nothing seems to work, i.e. I can't find appropiate morphsims $s,t$ such that
$$sw_3t=w$$
so that I can use the universal property of the epi-mono factorization.

I'm convinced this must be the correct approach. Does someone know how to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another approach might be to prove in general: for $p,q,r : U \to \Omega$, $p \le p \curlyvee q$; $q \le p \curlyvee q$; and if $p \le r$ and $q\le r$, then $p \curlyvee q \le r$.  Then the associativity and commutativity properties would be easy to prove using these facts.

Comment: Anyway, your second version of $w_3$ should certainly have image with characteristic function giving the three-way $\curlyvee$.  (The first version looks more like $[(p\leftrightarrow q) \land r] \lor [(p\leftrightarrow r) \land q] \lor [(q\leftrightarrow r) \land p]$, which even in $\mathsf{Set}$ wouldn't give the right answer for $(\top,\top,\bot)$.)

Comment: On second thought, the second one would correspond to $(p\land q)\lor (p\land r)\lor (q\land r)$ so it wouldn't be right for $(\top,\bot,\bot)$.  I think what you really need is $w_3 = [\langle \top_{\Omega^2}, (\pi_1)_{\Omega^2}, (\pi_2)_{\Omega^2}\rangle, \langle (\pi_1)_{\Omega^2}, \top_{\Omega^2}, (\pi_2)_{\Omega^2} \rangle, \langle (\pi_1)_{\Omega^2}, (\pi_2)_{\Omega^2}, \top_{\Omega^2}\rangle ]$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thanks!! I will try to fill in the details. How did you get this intuition on what will work? Also, my next question will be on distributivity :)

Comment: If you want to get complex enough to prove distributivity, then almost certainly the easiest way will be to prove that $(\Omega, \curlywedge, \curlyvee, \top, \bot, {\rightarrow})$ forms a Heyting algebra object of the topos.  (Especially since not every lattice is distributive, so the existence of the relative complement $\rightarrow$ will presumably be involved eventually in any proof, at least in some implicit way.)

Comment: As for "intuition on what will work": I was asking myself what would be the union of the subobjects with characteristic functions $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3 : \Omega^3 \to \Omega$ - which would be the image of the coproduct.  And then the subobject with characteristic function $\pi_1$ is just $\langle \top_{\Omega^2}, (\pi_1)_{\Omega^2}, (\pi_2)_{\Omega^2} \rangle$, etc.

Comment: To be honest, if you eventually want to get to proving distributivity, then my method of choice would probably be to start bootstrapping some of the Kripke-Joyal semantics of the internal language of a topos...