Elementary proofs of distributive and other properties of $\land$, $\lor$, $\neg$ in topos?
Take the 'logical' arrows $\wedge \colon \Omega \times \Omega \to \Omega$, $\lor \colon \Omega \times \Omega \to \Omega$, $\neg \colon \Omega  \to \Omega$, defined by the usual pullback squares, as in Goldblatt's classic §6.6.
If e.g. $\chi, \psi \colon X \to \Omega$ are parallel arrows into the truth-value object, then we can compose $\wedge \circ \langle \chi, \psi \rangle$: or equivalently, using suggestive infix notation, we could write that composite as $\chi \wedge \psi$. Similarly for $\chi \lor \psi$.
Now, we know that the $\wedge$, $\lor$, $\neg$ behave intuitionistically in any elementary topos. We have e.g.

$\chi \wedge \psi = \psi \wedge \chi$
$\chi \wedge (\psi \lor \phi) = (\chi \wedge \psi) \lor (\chi \wedge \phi)$
$\neg(\chi \lor \psi) = \neg\chi \wedge \neg\psi$
...

OK: it is easy to prove 1 by an elementary argument (relying on the isomorphism that swaps $A \times B$ with $B \times A$). But the likes of 2 and 3 seem a lot messier to prove just from definitions and elementary facts about products and pullbacks (e.g. from what's available by §6.6 in Goldblatt).
So here's the question -- I confess I lazily don't want to set about re-inventing the wheel here!

If you want to point completists/masochists to an elementary diagram
chase proving 2 or 3 (for example), is there a tolerably neat version available anywhere out there?

I've tried a few books and sets of lecture handouts without joy.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799008/asociativity-of-disjunction-in-elementary-toposes

I'm not sure whether the exact thing you ask for exists. Do you know how to prove that $\Omega$ is an internal Heyting algebra, as in Mac Lane-Moerdijk VI.6,8? That's a much healthier approach IMO.

@KevinCarlson To be sure. But there is some (minimal!) interest I guess in checking  what you can squeeze out of minimal resources in elementary ways.

Sure, the goal seems defensible, I was just making sure I understood what you want.
